# Show records from two tables where columns is equal

Tags: mysql

Assume from TABLE A, I have **EID's** (2,3,4) under my account, In TABLE B I want to show all records **where DEP is equal to EID** .

Thank you,

Table A

```
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           id   |   EID  |   EC  |
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           1    |    2   |   M   +
           2    |    2   |   Y   +
           3    |    3   |   S   +
           4    |    3   |   Q   +
           5    |    4   |   L   +
           6    |    5   |   I   +
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Table B

```
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           A    |    B   |  DEP  |
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           1    |    2   |   2   +
           2    |    2   |   2   +
           3    |    3   |   3   +
           4    |    3   |   3   +
           5    |    4   |   4   +
           6    |    5   |   5   +
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here's the output I want to achieve.

```
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          Results                |
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
           1    |    2   |   2   +
           2    |    2   |   2   +
           3    |    3   |   3   +
           4    |    3   |   3   +
           5    |    4   |   4   +
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: The tables and columns in your query are nothing like the tables and columns you listed.

Comment: I remove the query cause i think it useless. thank you :)

Comment: You should replace it with what you actually tried.

Comment: 5 is also equal for both tables EID and DEP

Comment: you mean added by editor?

Comment: Couldn't Understande the Differencr between Col **B** and **DEP** of **TableB**.

Comment: @Jason what do you mean 5 is not mine ?

Comment: 5 is not under my account. @Minesh

Comment: this is a very simple logic, but I couldn't find a solution. my only problem is how will I fetch my EID's 2,3,4 and then process it to table b in single query.

Comment: Also B1 is the same as a2 (and vice versa) so you should have 4 rows for eid = 2 and 4 rows for eid = 3.

Answer (score 0):

***I have EID's (2,3,4) under my account***

```
select distinct B.A, B.B, A.EID  
from TableB B
inner join TableA A on A.EID=B.DEP
where A.EID in (2,3,4)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b1df/2)**

Comment: This is close, but I want it to be dynamically.

Comment: then just remove `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Jason But how did you come to know 2,3,4 are in your Account.

Comment: @luv exactly, that's my problem. If i wanted to change my EID then I need to change also the WHERE clause, What I want to achieve is. Fetch my EID's and then Fetch records in TABLE B where EID's is equal to DEP.

Comment: If I change my EID's in my table A. then it there's no problem in TABLE B.

Comment: @Jason is there a table where **EID** from which you come to know which EID are in your account?

Comment: Hi @Luv How can I make this dynamically? **where A.EID in (2,3,4)** I mean, I do not want the 2,3,4 to be inserted in WHERE clause?

Comment: @Jason That's what i am asking, ***is there a table where EID from which you come to know which EID are in your account***, then i can make it dynamic . And you need to maintained that table onlu.

Comment: Hi @Luv yes. theres a table.,

Comment: @Jason Just give me the field name and table name and if possible you can provide me the dummy data too.

Comment: hi @Luv sorry, Don't worry I have resolve this issue. thanks a bunch!